# Node with typescript: TS1123: Variable declaration list cannot be empty

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am new to TS and trying to play around with it. In my node app, I did a console log in `temp.ts` file

```
console.log("test");
```

The IntelliJ is giving me the following error:

```
TS1123: Variable declaration list cannot be empty
```

However when I run it with node I am getting

```
>node temp.ts
test1
```

Any idea what's going wrong with TS here?

Update: It's happening only with IntelliJ.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code as TypeScript. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB00QHMAUAiALrCn0EoBuIA). If Webstorm is giving you that error, either A) It's related to different code, not the code in the question; or B) Webstorm has some weird configuration error.

Comment: yes, the issue is with intellij, I tried it on VS code it is fine there. Sorry it was not webstorm. Updated the question.

Comment: I have the same error in Webstorm. Don't know how to solve it yet

Answer (score 7):

I had similar error and just restarted IntelliJ, then it luckily went way.

Comment: for me it was enough to `Restart TypeScript Service` (in the footer, there is TypeScript version number, left click on that opens a menu with this option)

Answer (score 2):

Press `Shift` `Shift`, search for "Restart typescript service" and execute it. This will usually solve if there's no actual errors in the file.